# How do I stop Unity Dash truncating file names?

Tags: files, unity-dash, search

When I'm looking for articles with long names in Unity dash, I would like to have the full filename displayed instead of the current truncated view.

It's difficult to find a specific article by searching on filters as it sometimes returns 10 or more results making it impossible, especially if you have a regular file naming convention e.g. YYYY-[Author Name]-Title

Displaying full document names similar to compact view of Nautilus would be helpful.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be No. Dash determines if you are using a desktop, laptop, or netbook, but after that the layout of the Dash results view is hardcoded. I saw no options available to change the layout or how it works.

Given the need to present a consistent appearance across platforms, especially phone and tablet, I can see how this is needed. I suspect such long file names would be a problem even for the equivalent of Nautilus compact view.

But you might file a bug report asking for the ability to see the full name in a tool tip or in the new preview view.

Another option would be to wrap a basic GUI, even something as simple as Zenity or Yad, or other GUI options using Python, Tcl/Tk, etc to create a simple way to browse and select these files.